# Match User placement in sshd_config

Tags: ssh

I want to do this in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Protocol                                     2
Ciphers                                      aes256-ctr
PermitRootLogin                              no

X11Forwarding                                no

Match User joebob
X11Forwarding yes

AuthorizedKeysFile                           .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitEmptyPasswords                         no
RSAAuthentication                            no
RhostsRSAAuthentication                      no
IgnoreUserKnownHosts                         no
```

Problem is

> Starting SSH daemon/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 40:
> Directive 'IgnoreUserKnownHosts' is not allowed within a Match block

It seems like however many directives after the first one after the Match statement is being including as part of the match?

My Match statement works if I put it at the very end of the `sshd_config` file.

I don't want to do that.

Is there a way I can have this one match statement near the top of the file, just after my X11Forwarding no statement?

I have all the pertinent ssh settings I care about at the top of the file, I want my match user right after X11forwarding no so I know it's happening.  I'll forget about it if it is placed at the bottom of the file.

My goal is to have X11Forwarding disabled for everyone except for one local user account defined in `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in `man sshd_config` and `Match` section :

> Only a subset of keywords may be used on the lines following a `Match` keyword. Available keywords are **AllowAgentForwarding, AllowTcpForwarding, Banner, ChrootDirectory, ForceCommand, GatewayPorts, GSSAPIAuthentication, HostbasedAuthentication, KbdInteractiveAuthentication, KerberosAuthentication, KerberosUseKuserok, MaxAuthTries, MaxSessions, PubkeyAuthentication, AuthorizedKeysCommand, AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs, PasswordAuthentication, PermitEmptyPasswords, PermitOpen, PermitRootLogin, RequiredAuthentications1, RequiredAuthentications2, RhostsRSAAuthentication, RSAAuthentication, X11DisplayOffset, X11Forwarding and X11UseLocalHost**

so fine, as you see `IgnoreUserKnownHosts` cannot be in Match section. either move that above first Match if you have or put all the `Match` parts (if any, one or more) at the end of configuration file (which is suggested); else all the configuration after Match will override global config and apply for that your user (`joebob`) only.

so suggested to move all your Match to the end of configuration file.

Note: Every `Match` block can end by starting another `Match` block or end of configuration file or if you type `Match All` every subsequent configuration after that will be considered as global.

Comment: So a `Match User whoever` will result in every subsequent line interpreted as being part of that match statement?

Comment: There is no `End Match User` type of statement?

Comment: Re:"_`So a Match User whoever will result in every subsequent line interpreted as being part of that match statement?`_", correct.

Comment: Re:"_`There is no End Match User type of statement? `_", no, it will end with another Match or end of configuration file. always put `Match` at the end of configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

To mark end of a Match block, you can use "Match all"

```
Protocol                                     2
Ciphers                                      aes256-ctr
PermitRootLogin                              no

X11Forwarding                                no

Match User joebob
X11Forwarding yes
Match all

AuthorizedKeysFile                           .ssh/authorized_keys
PermitEmptyPasswords                         no
RSAAuthentication                            no
RhostsRSAAuthentication                      no
IgnoreUserKnownHosts                         no
```